# maven build fails due to validate-code-format, is there a way to skip the format validation?

Tags: java, maven, code-formatting, maven-bom

I have a project `Project C` which has a dependency on the Maven's Bill of Materials (BOM) parent project `Project P`. The parent project `Project P` contains some of the code styles.

I do not which to apply these code styles to my child project `Project C` due to which when I run the `mvn clean install` on the child project `Project C`, I get the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.cosium.code:git-code-format-maven-plugin:3.4:validate-code-format (validate-code-format) on project project-c: Execution validate-code-format of goal com.cosium.code:git-code-format-maven-plugin:3.4:validate-code-format failed: 
An API incompatibility was encountered while executing com.cosium.code:git-code-format-maven-plugin:3.4:validate-code-format: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.google.googlejavaformat.java.JavaInput (in unnamed module @0x4a320414) 
cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.parser.Tokens$TokenKind (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.parser to unnamed module @0x4a320414
```

I would like to turn off the checkstyle option in maven and would like to build the project. How to achieve this?

I looked at some answers like:

```
<skip>${skipFormatCode}</skip>
```

but nothing seems to work and getting the same error. Please suggest some work-arounds to this issue.